# Is there any way to use /fill on just the air blocks of a selected area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Specifically im trying to get it so i can put a blanket of fire down on a non flat terrain, i was thinking the clone of fill command but any way i try it theres always a possibility it'll remove blocks around me. i was also thinking falling sand and then replacing it but that kind of ruins the visual effect i want unless there a way to make the sand invisible

Comment: If colorfusion helped, consider marking his answer correct

Answer (score 2):

Yep, `/fill` allows you to specify `keep` as an `[oldBlockHandling]` mode, and thus only replace air. Try this:

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 fire 0 keep
```

Comment: Nice answer colorfusion!

Comment: This is a simple concept, but it is good of you to tell those who do not know of it. the other '[oldBlockHandling]' modes are 'replace' (normal mode, can have a block ID after it to specify 1 replaced block) 'destroy' (same as 'replace' but creates destruction particles and drop items) 'hollow' (creates a hollow box with air inside) and 'outline' (same as 'hollow' but keeps blocks _inside_ and not _on the filled blocks_)